# Python imaplib search Variables

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to do a search using imaplib with variables. When I hard code the information the search works great.

```
result, data = mail.search(None,'(SENTSINCE "15-Oct-2015" SENTBEFORE "19-Oct-2015")'.format(date=date))
```

I've tried lots of ways to setup variables and from other posts it seems the best way is setup the entire search parameters as the variable and call it that way.

```
search_string = '(SENTSINCE \"' + start_date_format + '\" SENTBEFORE \"' + format_endday + '\" )\'.format(date=date)'
result, data = mail.search(None, search_string)
```

The print of the variable setup looks accurate:

```
(SENTSINCE "12-Oct-2015" SENTBEFORE "19-Oct-2015" )'.format(date=date)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "infringment-report.py", line 74, in <module>
    result, data = mail.search(None, search_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 639, in search
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, *criteria)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1087, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 917, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['The specified message set is invalid.']
```

I've been banging my head on this for a while, an help is appreciated.

Comment: I would also love to know how to use variables inside imaplib search!

Answer (score 0):

I am also a newbie in python and imaplib but i guess this will work just fine.

For retrieving mails having name  stored in a variable say fromname
then

```
let criteria = ['From', fromname]
typ, [msg_id] = mail.search(None, *criteria).
```